# Shouldn't "git pull --rebase --autostash" always pop the stash automatically? Even when there are conflicts?

Tags: git, rebase

In a previous job, a couple of years ago, we used git with an (old) plugin, called "**git up**".
https://github.com/aanand/git-up
"This plugin is no longer maintained or supported."
Updating your workspace used to be very easy:
just type "git up", see what files have conflicts, edit those to resolve the conflicts, do a "git add", and you are done.

I am now working for another company. They started to use git earlier this year.
We don't have a clear and simple way for everyone to update our workspace.
I would like to introduce a very simple way to update your workspace. **As simple as possible**. No commits, no merges.

It seems the simplest way to do this is by using "git pull" with the --rebase and --autostash flags.
You can do the same by setting these values in your .gitconfig file.
Or with an alias:

```
git config --global alias.up '!git fetch && git rebase --autostash origin'
```

This kinda works.
When there are no conflicts, the stash pops automatically.
Besides typing "git up" or "git pull --rebase --autostash", there is nothing I need to do.

There is one issue.
When there are conflicts, git refuses to apply the stash back into my workspace.
It says:

```
Applying autostash resulted in conflicts.
Your changes are safe in the stash.
You can run "git stash pop" or "git stash drop" at any time.
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main.
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: autostash
$
```

When I then type "git stash pop" the stash is popped, my local changes are automatically edited into my workspace again (with the usual >>>> and <<<< markers). This always succeeds.

Note, git always refuses to automatically pop the stash when I have changed a file that is also changed on the remote repository. Not only when there is a real conflict (changes on the same lines). But also when my change is nowhere near the change from the remote repository. This makes me suspect that the behaviour I see is really not intended.

But why does --autostash not pop the stash automatically?
I spoke with my company's git support persons.
They also expect the stash to pop automatically.
Even when there are conflicts.
I did a bit of googling. Nothing I found suggests that the stash should not pop automatically.

So my question:
What can I expect? **Should the stash always pop automatically** when I use --autostash?
Or is the behaviour I see normal?
Is this a bug?
Did our local git-team change something in the executables or global config? (They say they didn't).

Behaviour is the same with 2.26.2 and 2.33. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior (er, behaviour) you see *is* normal, because the operation *is still in progress*.  The autostash should be popped—or rather, dropped—after the operation is complete.  It's true that in this case, the rebase *portion* of the operation is done, but the stash did not apply cleanly, so the `git stash apply` step has failed:

```
Applying autostash resulted in conflicts.
```

(I *think* Git did a `git reset --hard` to erase the attempt to `git stash apply`, making you do it on your own at this point, but I don't use autostash.  Note that running `git stash pop` will get *conflicts* and will only *apply*, not drop, the stash.)

I personally dislike autostash because it's overly complicated: it consists of a multi-step operation, involving making stash commits, rebasing, then applying-and-dropping the stash commits.  Instead of *stashing*, I recommend that you just *commit before rebasing*.  This way the last commit is part of the rebase, so there's just one operation to finish.

You can use `git reset` to remove the rebased commit once you're all done, if that's even needed: I like to have smaller commits that I can combine later when they're "ready for prime time" as it were, and leaving a bunch of small "this isn't what I want but it's progress" commits in my in-progress work helps that out.  Eventually, I run a `git rebase -i`, or series of them, to sort and combine the mini-commits.

(Not to make this a mini-rant against `git stash`, but ... `git stash` itself is bad in general.  Avoid it.)

Comment: So typing "git pull --rebase --autostash" is overly complicated.

But doing git add, git commit, git fetch, git rebase, git reset, git rebase -i, keeping your changes spread out over multiple diffs (and probably more "handy" tricks) is easy?

I like simple stuff. I want simplicity for my colleagues too. Typing one command would be perfect, if the autostash would just always pop by itself.
I still don't understand why the "git up" plugin could update your workspace and merge in changes/conflicts by itself. And "git pull --rebase --autostash" can not.

Comment: Git, alas, *isn't* simple, and attempts to make it simple always fail. The problem itself—distributed source management—isn't simple. Git is a little more complicated than necessary: Mercurial got a few things "righter", as it were. But aside from most Git tutorials and introductions being terrible, most of Git's visible complexities aren't gratuitous.

Comment: The fact that git is not simple does not mean it SHOULD not be simple. If we always had that attitude, we'd all still be programming in assembler ("Programming, alas, isn't simple").

Let's not have that discussion. You can't convince me. I only need to do 3 things with git (clone, update and create a pull-request). So I think (the first 2 of) those should be triggered with a simple single-line command.

The old "git up" plugin could do it. We can apply the stash manually. So why can't autostash not do autopop? I see no reason why not. It would make life a bit simpler for 90% of git users.

Comment: So nobody has anything useful to say?

Except: "I don't like the way you are trying to do things", and "git is hard and confusing, get used to it".

I have looked for an semi-official support forum for git. A point of contact where you can report bugs or request features. I have found none. Anything has an idea where I can go? A flag or option to force "git rebase --autostash" to always pop would be good enough.

Comment: You asked a relatively simple question with a yes or no answer ("is it supposed to do that") to which the answer is "yes, it is supposed to do that". There *is* a Git *mailing list* for reporting bugs or requesting features, but that's not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, it was a relatively simple question. And I got relatively simply the wrong answer here. No big deal, because nobody so far have been able to answer my simple question: "isn't this supposed to work automatically?". It does. After posting my last comment, I went looking for official support channels. On the git mailing-list there was a conversation from a few months ago, indicating that autostash was broken. So I cloned the git source, checkout out the latest test-version (next). And low and behold, the pop does happen automatically again. Like I think it should. So it was a bug after all.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a bug. When using autostash, the stash is supposed to pop automatically. Even when there are conflicts. As I expected. Somewhere earlier this year (or last year) someone broke that functionality. I checked the lastest version ("next") of the git source code. And the pop again happens automatically.

There is one remaining problem. After the pop, and after the changes get applied without problems, I expect the stash to get deleted (dropped) automatically too. That doesn't happen. I don't know if that is intentionally, or also a bug. I suspect it is a bug. If everything applies fine, why keep the stash? I bet nobody knows and nobody dares to make a decision to fix this or not.

The sad thing is: I asked a whole bunch of people whether current behaviour (no automatic pop) is intentional or a bug. Colleagues, the guy who installed/maintains our git, our in-house git support people, our local git-experts, our external git-support team. And here. I got a zillion answers. None of them were correct. Most didn't even answer the question: "I don't like rebase, I don't like autostash, I don't like stash, why don't you do what I do, that is way better". And nobody actually answered my question. I don't blame the people here who tried to answer, but after 2 months rowing against the stream, I got a bit irritated. Sorry.

I'm happy I persisted. I'm happy the problem will be fixed soon. Now the only thing remaining is to make sure the stash gets dropped when we don't need it anymore. If necessary, I'll fix it myself and offer the fix to the git repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think in case of a conflict you may want to go back to where you started. The changes from the rebase may not be worth to do integration work. Instead you may want to reset --hard to the commit from which the stash was done on, pop the stash and finish your work in the working directory. Finalize it with a commit, push it, request a merge request and let somebody else solve the conflict.

Therefore I see the point behind keeping it in case of a conflict. It keeps you both ways open, either integrate now and drop it or drop the work been done (having led to the conflict) and return to where you started. I don't see a need to keep the stash in case there was no conflict and would only judge this as a bug.